# C# JSON Object query

Tags: c#, json

I'm having a bit of difficulty in searching a JSON object, mainly because a relatively new programmer.
The first thing I need to do is retrieve a JSON table which has the following format:

```
{
    "1": {
        "10": 1,
        "15": 1,
        "17": 1,
        "20": 1,
        "40": 2
    },
    "7": {
        "20": 2
    },
    "12": {
        "40": 2
    },
    "14": {
        "17": 2
    },
    "15": {
        "10": 2,
        "15": 1,
        "17": 2,
        "20": 3
    }
}
```

Here we have two records (in reality there will be 300 - 400).  I put this in an JSON Object.

Next I receive JSON records in pseudo real time with the following format:

```
{
    "Call": "VR2XMT",
    "Spotter": "UA4HTT",
    "Comment": "strong",
    "Freq": 28497,
    "Band": 10,
    "Dxcc": 321,
    "Date": "2014-03-13T13:40:50.484133322Z"
}
```

If you look at the table, "1" or "7" represents the datavalue of "Dxcc":321, in the records.  "Band" represents the nested keys in the table.
What my query needs to do is see if the "Dxcc" exists in the table and if the "Band" exists for that record.
I have no clue on how to do this.  I tried converting to a dictionary but this didn't work.
Here is the basic code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {

            var data = client.DownloadString("url");
            JObject o;
            o = JObject.Parse(data);
        }

        using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
        {
            using (var socket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.SUB))
            {
                socket.SubscribeAll();
                socket.Connect("tcp://clublog.org:7373");

                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    var replyMsg = socket.Receive(Encoding.UTF8);

                    Console.WriteLine(replyMsg);

                }
                socket.UnsubscribeAll();
                socket.Close();
            }
        }  
    }        
}
}
```

Can someone please help out here?  I am not even sure if one could query this directly or if I need to put this in a dictionary or what?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the requirements for the question. I see you parsing the data into a JObject, however you don't do anything with the data after. Could you clarify the requirements and give a more pinpoint question?
In the meantime http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm might be what you want.

Comment: You can see at : http://www.clublog.org:7373/

Comment: What is your problem here? What does not work, have you an exception, an unexpected result?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I have a suspicion that your first object might not be the best design. Is there any way to refactor so it can be serialized to a class?

Comment: Actually I don't do anything with the data yet.....that's why I'm asking.  I don't have a clue where to go now.

Comment: What I want to do, is check if the JSON message exists in the JSON Object.  So for example, in the message, I have DXCC = 321. The 321 corresponds to the keys in the JObject. I also need to quesrry the sub records for the sub keys and there might have an entry for "10" with a value.  If the record exists I will do nothing.  If it doesn't exist I will put the JSON message into a table elsewhere.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, deserialize your table into a nested dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> table =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>(data);
```

Then, create a helper method that can check whether a given pair of `Dxcc` and `Band` exist in the table:

```
static bool Exists(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dict, string dxcc, string band)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> inner;
    return (dict.TryGetValue(dxcc, out inner) && inner.ContainsKey(band));
}
```

Later, when you are receiving your messages inside your loop, you can deserialize each one into a `JObject`, extract the `Dxcc` and `Band` values, and call the helper method:

```
    JObject jo = JObject.Parse(replyMsg);

    string dxcc = jo["Dxcc"].ToString();
    string band = jo["Band"].ToString();

    if (!Exists(table, dxcc, band))
    {
        // doesn't exist, so do something with the replyMsg
    }
```

Comment: Hi Brian.  As it turns out, I read the reference above and tried something.  Essentially, I found a simple solution, but I don't really understand why it works.  I do use the second part of your reply as well.

Comment: Your way is essentially the same thing except you deserialize your lookup table into a `JObject` instead of a dictionary.  `JObject` behaves like a dictionary, so you can query it for keys in much the same way.  If your code works, stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I used the link above and did this:

```
                while (true)
                {
                    string msgDXCC;
                    string band;

                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                    var spot = socket.Receive(Encoding.UTF8);

                    if (spot != "")
                    {
                        spotMsg = JObject.Parse(spot);

                        msgDXCC = (string)spotMsg["Dxcc"];
                        band = (string)spotMsg["Band"];

                        var keyPresent = o.Property(msgDXCC);

                        if (keyPresent != null)
                        {
                            string qsoStatus = (string)o[msgDXCC][band];

                            if (qsoStatus == null)
                            {
                                //add record


                            }

                            else
                            {
                                //do nothing
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

It's now working exactly as expected.
But, is Brians answer a better solution?
Thanks